# Publish type declarations outside @types

Tags: npm, typescript2.0

I have created an npm library but I don't want to publish it in the public repository (So I cannot use @typings npm package to put my typings there). On the other side, I don't want to put `.d.ts` file into that package but wanted to publish another package called `lib-typings`.

Is it possible to consume `lib-typings` for a library called `lib` in Typescript 2?

Comment: You should be able to use the `typeRoots` and `types` options to do what you want: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Why do you want to separate code and typings and don't to have them in one place?

Comment: @cartant Didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cartant said, property `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json` is for addressing this problem.